# Zend custom validator not found on remote server

Tags: zend-framework, validation, zend-validate

I know that there are some similar questions, but the answers from there don't help me.

The application worked alright locally, but now, among other problems, the classes of the custom validators i made are not found, although some model classes (i haven't tested all yet) work. It doesn't seem to be a problem of case sensitivity, class names, file names or folder names.

Could there be some other causes?

Comment: framework version might be different?

Comment: Well there could be, but you haven't given much to go on. What code is giving you problems and what error messages are you getting. Please read the [FAQ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem maybe a week ago. It was a problem with the path to library. I did it like this:

In public/index.php:

```
defined('LIBRARY_PATH') || define('LIBRARY_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../library'));
```

And in application/Bootsrap.php I have something like:

```
protected function _initAutoload() {

    // configure new autoloader
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader ( array ('namespace' => '', 'basePath' => LIBRARY_PATH ) );

    // autoload validators definition
    $autoloader->addResourceType ( 'Validator', '/validate', 'MyValidate' );
}
```